# Automatically add certain properties to markdown tags

Tags: ruby, markdown, jekyll

I use Markdown to write posts on my websites. 
Sometimes I have to link to other pages on my website, other times to external links. I would like to automatically add the properties `rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank"` whenever I have an external markdown link. In other words, the links

```
 [External](www.google.com)
 [Internal](/posts/another)
```

would translate to

```
  <a href="www.google.com" rel="nofollow noopener noreferrer" target="_blank">External</a>
  <a href="/posts/another">Internal</a>
```

Is this possible? How can I go about coding this?

I am using Kramdown, but I can also use other markdown engines.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a Jekyll plugin. Not sure if there are better solutions.

```rb
require "kramdown"

module Kramdown
  class Converter::Html
    alias_method :super_convert_a, :convert_a
    def convert_a el, indent

      if ( el.attr["href"] =~ /^[A-Za-z0-9]+:/ )
        el.attr["target"] = "_blank"
        el.attr["rel"] = "nofollow noopener noreferrer"
      end

      super_convert_a el, indent
    end
  end
end
```

I use relative urls for my internal links.